# Dreamweaver CS6 - default HTML5 new document code modification

Tags: dreamweaver

I would like to set up my "Default.html" file in Dreamweaver CS6 to have an additional code. More specifically, I would like to the new HTML5 document to have an extra 3 lines of code.

I have been searching everywhere to find out how to do it without success.
The closest I got is here (for Dreamweaver MX): http://www.sitepoint.com/customize-dreamweaver-needs/

When I look under "Document Types" ... I don't have "New documents" folder...
AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6\en_US\Configuration\DocumentTypes

Can you please point me where and how to edit the default HTML5 new document?

I have Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 (version 12.0 build 5842).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS6\configuration\DocumentTypes\MMDocumentTypeDeclarations.xml**

This is where the DOCTYPE headers are stored.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS6\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments\Default.html**

This is where the Default.html is stored, editing this may do what you want